# Payment method form not visible before click

Tags: magento, payment-method

We have created custom payment method. The method contains inputs etc in its `form.phtml` file. In checkout, we get to Payment methods and our method is checked, but its form is not visible until we check it again. We can click continue, but it throws exception that we need to fill those inputs. However, user does not see them so he'll be confused.

[Real situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nMT6.png)
[Expected situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hET2t.png)

Do we need to add any property?

Comment: Can you please share any screenshot for same?

Comment: I added images to question

Comment: I followed this and my custom payment method is working fine..you can also check: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method/

Comment: I do not see difference.

Comment: is there any error showing in console?

Comment: No, there isn't any

Comment: Are there any JS error in browser console?

Comment: No, there aren't any errors. Our payment method is visible if I click it then, it is working.. It just isn't visible when I enter the checkout section for the first time.

Comment: You need to work on js for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I added JS to `form.phtml` and it is working now.

```
var customMethodCheckbox document.getElementById("p_method_custom_method");
var customForm = document.getElementById("payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>");

if(customMethodCheckbox.checked){
    customForm.style.display = "";
}
```

Once `form.phtml` is loaded, it triggers this JS. If custom payment method is checked as default, it removes `display: none` attribute from custom form and displays it. And you don't need to worry about changing payment methods etc, because it is solved by Magento.